# Is it possible to orbifold torus $T^d$ into a sphere $S^d$ using $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, orbifolds

A related question for $d=2$ has already been raised (and positively answered) at Math StackExchange here: [Is it possible to obtain a sphere from a quotient of a torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829146/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-sphere-from-a-quotient-of-a-torus) It is also trivially true for $d=1$, since $T^1=S^1$. I am wondering, whether this generalizes for higher dimensions as well.

Specifically, consider a torus $T^d$ constructed as a cube $[-1,1]^d$ with identified faces. Then additionally identify points $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $-\boldsymbol{r}$ within this cube to create an orbifold $T^d/\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is the result of such a procedure homeomorphic to sphere $S^d$?

For $d=2$ it can be easily shown that indeed $T^2/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong S^2$. The described procedure is equivalent to the one suggested by user126154 at the linked StackExchange question. It's also easy to visualize since both $S^2$ and $T^2$ are easily handled in 3 spatial dimensions.

But plain visualization fails for $d>2$ and I don't really know how to prove/disprove this kind of statements.