# Orbit space of $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on the torus $T^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ be the group $\{1,-1\}$. I want to construct an action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on the torus $T^2$ such that the orbit space is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$. Could anyone give some hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to obtain a sphere from a quotient of a torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829146/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-sphere-from-a-quotient-of-a-torus) (The group action is a rotation by 180 degrees)